# Inverted index on a custom field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm evaluating ES as a storage technology for my data-intensive use case (billions of data-cells).

The use case is rather simple, but we need blazing fast response times.

- We would be storing documents like: `{ id_1: long, id_2: long, field_1: long, field_2: long, .... field_N:long }`
- Read pattern expressed in SQL would be like: `SELECT id_2 FROM index WHERE id_1 = ? AND field_1 > ?`

`id_1` naturally fits to a routing field role. It would put all data having the same `id_1` to a single shard and this allows to execute the query in one shard because `id_1` is a query condition.

ES would most likely execute the `SELECT ...` query as follows:

- locate the shard storing documents with given `id_1` value (using the routing field feature)
- lookup reversed indexes and find document ids matching the query condition
- lookup documents matching document ids found in previous step
- prepare a projection to a selected field `id_2`

This looks really promising, however i wonder if it's possible to make it faster.

If ES would maintain an inverted index with values of the `id_2` field in addition to document ids then the query execution could be quicker. It would be enough to just merge matching `id_2` values returned by the reversed indexes applied in the query condition and return them to the client without making a document lookup. Though i just want to do `SELECT id_2 FROM ...`.

Are my assumptions correct? Is it possible to optimize ES in a way i described?

Comment: E.S is highly optimized for text-search & aggregation use cases (Memory usage will be very significant). Based on what you have described, it looks neither of them is your use case. Your app is read intensive or write ?  Have you evaluated any other option as well e.g CockroachDb etc?

Comment: @SahilGupta I will be writing millions of such documents. Reads in the beginning will be following the pattern I described, but soon I might also have other read uses cases based on text-based fields. ES promises a lot of flexibility thus I'm looking at it.

PS: thanks for the hint about CockroachDB. I didn't look at it so far, but now i will

Comment: Please do estimate the cost, it would incur over a period of 3-4 years.

Comment: If my comment answered your query i will pop-it out as an answer. Please do let me know .